# ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END Mongoose Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

While in debug mode, if my server is left running for quite sometime (often overnight), I arrive to see this.

```
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end
    at writeAfterEnd (_stream_writable.js:243:12)
    at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:291:5)
    at Connection.write (C:\Git\webUI\development\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:734:57)
    at C:\Git\webUI\development\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:1563:44
    at waitForAuth (C:\Git\webUI\development\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:1417:40)
    at C:\Git\webUI\development\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:1425:5
    at C:\Git\webUI\development\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:1278:23
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at writeAfterEnd (_stream_writable.js:245:10)
    at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:291:5)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
```

It doesn't point to anywhere in my code which could possibly be the origin of the error.

Mongo connection function:

```
function mongoConnect() {

    var options = {
        keepAlive: 1,
        connectTimeoutMS: 5000, // ms. default = 30000
        reconnectTries: 1000, // default = 30
        reconnectInterval: 5000, // ms. default = 1000
        family: 4, // force IPV4 to speed up connection

        // set this to remove a deprecation warning. See mongoose issue: 6890
        useCreateIndex: true,
        useNewUrlParser: true,
    };

    try {
        mainLogger.info(`connecting to: mongodb://${process.env.mongoServerIP}:${process.env.mongoServerPort}/${process.env.mongoDatabaseName}`);
        mongoose.connect(`mongodb://${process.env.mongoServerIP}:${process.env.mongoServerPort}/${process.env.mongoDatabaseName}`, options);
    } catch (error) {
        mainLogger.error(`Error while connecting to mongo DB: ${error}`);
    }

    return mongoose.connection;
}
```

Mongo event handlers:

```
mongoConnect()
    .on("error", function (...messages) {

        mainLogger.error(`Mongo connection error: ${JSON.stringify(messages)}`);

        fatalError.error = true;
        fatalError.mongoConnectError = true;
        fatalError.mongoErrorMessages = messages;

        mainLogger.error(messages);

        listen();

    })
    .on("disconnected", mongoConnect())
    .once("open", function (...messages) {

        mainLogger.info("Mongo connected successfully.");

        fatalError.error = false;
        fatalError.mongoConnectError = false;
        fatalError.mongoErrorMessages = messages;

        if (messages.length > 0)
            mainLogger.info(messages);

        listen();
    });
```

Can anyone provide any pointers to the origin of the issue?

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I'm having the same issue

Comment: I wasn't able to fix it unfortunately, I haven't seen this error in some time though... Maybe mongoose released an update which addresses this issue.